# How can make (style =“display: none;”) element visible in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

```
<div class="clearfix entry_but_bar_out clearfix" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="entry_but_bar_in clearfix"><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-colored_2 entry-cevapla" onclick="return sspot.entry.cevapla_goster(this,'208281235');">‹ yanıtla</a><a href="/e/208281235/?tab=duzenle" class="btn btn-xs btn-colored_2" data-placement="bottom" title="düzenle">edit</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-colored_2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" onclick="return sspot.entry.sil(this, '208281235');" data-original-title="sil">sil</a><a href="/?sa=msj&amp;kimek=leb-demeden-sakso&amp;id=208281235" class="btn btn-xs btn-colored_2" data-placement="bottom" title="mesaj at">mesaj</a><a href="/e/208281235/?tab=gammaz" class="btn btn-xs btn-colored_2" data-placement="bottom" title="gammazla bunu">gammazla</a><a href="/e/208281235/" class="btn btn-xs btn-colored_2">#208281235</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-colored_2" onclick="return sspot.entry.paylas('208281235','face')"><i class="ssicon-facebook"></i></a>
                                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-colored_2" onclick="return sspot.entry.paylas('208281235','twit')"><i class="ssicon-twitter"></i></a>
                        </div><!-- entry_but_bar_in clearfix -->
                    </div>
```

i'm trying to make elements visible and click on it . But it doesn't work ,

```
clicking = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="middle-block"]/ol/li/div/div[3]/div[2]/span')
browser.execute_script("removeAttribute('display:none');",clicking)
clicking.click()
```

Comment: this link has `onclick="return sspot.entry.paylas('208281235','twit')"` so you can try to run `execute_script("sspot.entry.paylas('208281235','twit')")`

Comment: using xpath like `/ol/li/div/div[3]/div[2]/span` often makes problem - better try to use classes. BTW: you try to remove `display:none` from `<span>` but it is in `<div style="display: none;">` But `span` and `div` usually are not clickable and you would have to find `<a`>` and click it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code and let me know if it works for you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
action = ActionChains(driver)

# Put your URL
driver.get('Your URL') 

time.sleep(5)

Target_Div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"clearfix entry_but_bar_out clearfix")]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display:\"true\"')", Target_Div)
```

Use the above code and make correction in your code.

Comment: is not working , display : 'true' have to be 'block' . It's working when im doing manual